# unity renderer material color accessing problem in mono develop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

why intellisense of my mono develop don't access renderer /material /color after this keyword e.g this.renderer.material.color giving a error in my mono develop ,whats my fault ?
c#, unity 3d,Mono develop

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material
```